# Difficulty with Motion/Pos etc. NBT manipulations

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm fairly (but not completely) new to the revised command block functionalities and functions themselves but I think I've got a pretty competent understanding to get me by.

Basically, I'm trying to create a "hose" mechanic where, when the player holds shift with a specific item (I can do that bit easy enough), it summons falling blocks in front of the player with a set "forward" motion that is relative to the player's facing direction. I've tried doing a ray-casting technique but I want the "water" coming from the hose to have a natural looking falling animation which ray-casting doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put your Pos[0], Pos[1], and Pos[2] in scoreboards (maybe playerX, playerY, and playerZ?) and spawn the falling block in one block in front of you with `^ ^ ^1`. Then put the block's coords in three different scoreboards (like projectileX, projectileY, and projectileZ, again using Pos[]).

You then subtract your position from the projectile's position one axis at a time (giving you three vectors) and save those into the Motion[] tags of the block using `execute store`. I won't have a computer for a few days but when I get to one I can write out the commands for it. This is easier in a function but you could do it with command blocks too if you wanted.

This question has the general commands, but shooting something different: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/349225/java-minecraft-1-13-summoned-projectiles-in-front-of-player-freeze-and-then-te